Probability of selecting a desired chip

Three players, say
$A,B,$ and $C$ are going to draw $5$ chips each (without replacement) out of a bag of $15$ chips numbers $1−15$. The order of selection is $A → B → C$. Given that player $A$ only selected even-numbered chips, find the probability that player $B$ selected Chip $12$.

I solved it as follows:
$P($$A$ doesn't select $12$ | $A$ selects an even number$)$ = $\frac{6 \choose 5}{7 \choose 5}$ = $\frac{2}{7}$
$P(B$ selects $12)$ = $P(B$ selects $12$ | $A$ doesn't selects $12)$$P($A doesn't selects $12)$ + $P(B$ selects $12$ | $A$ selects $12)P(A$ selects $12)$
$P(B$ selects $12)$ = $P(B$ selects $12$ | $A$ doesn't selects $12)$$P($A doesn't selects $12)$ + $0$
$P(B$ selects $12)$ = $\frac{{1 \choose 1} \times {13 \choose 4}}{{14 \choose 5}} \times \frac{2}{7} = \frac{5}{49}$
I simulated and got $1/7$ as the answer. Where am I going wrong?

$B$ is choosing from a reduced pool of $10$ remaining numbers.
$P(B$ selects $12)=\frac{{1 \choose 1} \times {9 \choose 4}}{{10 \choose 5}} \times \frac{2}{7} = \frac{1}{7}$

Oh! How did I overlook that!! Thank you so much!

Just use symmetry.  $A$ chooses $5$ of the $7$ even numbers.  That means that there is a $\frac 27$ chance that $\#12$ is still in play.  Then, given that $A$ skipped $\#12$,  there is a $\frac 12$ chance that it goes to $B$ and not $C$.  And, of course, $\frac 27\times \frac 12=\frac 17$.

I think you are over complicating the scenario, or perhaps l am over simplifying. Theres 7 even chips. And 8 odd chips. Player A picked 5 even chips.  So for player B there are only 10 chips remaining to grab, only 2 of which are even. Player A has a ~70% chance to grab the 12 with their 5 turns. Player B only has a 20% chance to grab an even number, let alone the 12
.2(player B chance to pull 12) x .7(player A chance to pull 12) = .14 which equals 1/7
Why do you think 1/7 is wrong?

I would argue that OP's way of writing is easier to read than this answer. It does provide a good intuition on what the solution should be nevertheless, it is not a formal proof

I agree, its much more formal. I also forget to factor in that if the 12 is still in there with the other 10, its only a 1 /10 chance for player B to get it. 2/10 player B grabs an even chip, 1/10 it is the 12. But lm not sure how to factor for the “unknown” if Player A ends up grabbing the 12 with the first 5 grabs


$P(B$ selects $12)$ = $\frac{{1 \choose 1} \times {13 \choose 4}}{{14 \choose 5}} \times \frac{2}{7} = \frac{5}{49}$

As other responses have indicated, a symmetry argument leads directly to the $~\dfrac{2}{7} \times \dfrac{1}{2}~$ computation.
However, the approach taken by the OP (i.e. original poster) as represented by the excerpted equations above is valid.  It is simply that the OP got the numbers wrong.
When you are assuming that $~A~$ did not select the '12', you are also assuming that $~A~$ selected $~5~$ other numbers from the set $~\{2,4,6,8,10,14\}.~$
You can assume, without loss of generality, that $~A~$ specifically selected the elements $~\{2,4,6,8,10\}.$
This implies that at the moment that $~B~$ is making their selection, that $~B~$ is selecting $~5~$ elements from the following set:
$$\{12\} \cup \{1,3,5,7,9,11,13,14,15\}.$$
Therefore, using the OP's valid approach, the corrected computation is
$$P( ~B ~\text{selects '12'} ~) = \frac{\binom{1}{1} ~\binom{9}{4}}{\binom{10}{5}} \times \frac{2}{7} = \frac{1 \times 126}{252} \times \frac{2}{7} = \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{2}{7}.$$
